Need help to build a momentary switch
So I´ve this scenario: Need to close a push button for a lapse of 500ms when 5V are detected and when this voltaje detected (5V) disappears, need to close the same push button again for another 500ms.
My challenge is not to do it with any Microcontroller, just with discrete electronics.-
Why? Well... Why not? lol
Thanks in advance!
Regards

This sounds like a homework question. When you say you "need to close a push button" do you mean you need to manipulate an actual, physical switch? Do you need to provide continuity between two arbitrary terminals? Or do you need to set a signal high? If it is homework, show us what work you've done already (none is insufficient) and where you are stuck.

Hi there! Thanks for help! Yeah, sound like homework but it´s for a stupid thing I want to automate at home for personal use. I need to manipulate a physical pushbutton making like it was actually pressed. I tinker with electronics for fun and actually I thought to build this without microcontrollers wich I think I can do it straigh away, but no joy to use a MCU for this. Thanks!

Alright then, what's the push button attached to? What are the voltage/current levels, how strict is the 500ms time requirement, how quickly does it need to respond, etc (edit this information into the original problem statement). It sounds like I'm picking this apart but I want to keep you from getting an answer and then have to go "oh but it's actually a 120VAC switch" and by that time your question's on page 2 and is basically lost.

The pushbutton is the on/off of a sound amplifier. I still not open it up to check what you asked. The time is not so stricted as with between 150ms and 1000ms it works the same. No need to be super fast.

WoW, what a Nice surprise of options. Ok. I Better Open the amplifier and check out how the power button works. Thought more to drive it with a MOSFET or 2n2222 than with a relay, but O Better check the button working than guessing. Thanks to you all.

First you need a relay that is going to be in parallel with your "pushbutton". You really don't want a servo/mechanical pieces (well the relay can be mechanical but never mind). Hopefully your "button" is single or double pole only, otherwise you may need more than one relay.
Then you need to activating circuit. I'd still advocate for a microcontroller, like ATtiny, it would be better, simpler and cheaper, but never mind again.
For your delay generator, take a NE555 and associated RC, feeding a transistor/resistor/diode to feed the relay.
For identifying the signal changes, use an xor with a RC cell on one input that will reset the monostable.
Thinking of it, you could make the monostable as well using another XOR gate and RC cell, avoiding the NE555 altogether.
And going further, if your relay coil is low-current enough, maybe you could use the two remaining XOR gates to drive it. CD5070 or 74xx86 would be your chip of choice.
Now finish your homework ;-)
